# simple category search form returns full text - but I need excerpts

Tags: pages, search, excerpt

I have member pages. I set their "membership type" as a certain category. I want to search the members now. I use this simple form that does what I need, except that I need the results to display as excerpts. Ideas?

```
<form method="get" id="search form" action="/">
<div>
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="hidden" value="22" name="cat" id="scat" />
<input type="submit" id="search_submit" name="Search" value="Search"/>
</div>
</form>
```

UPDATE

I dropped into the theme and found search.php and saw:

```
<div class="entry">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div><!-- /.entry -->
```

I changed to:

```
<div class="entry">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div><!-- /.entry -->
```

I think that did the trick! So...I guess I answered my own question! :) || Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whats the loop look like on your search.php page? That's the search results template, and that's where the different output - either the_excerpt or the_content - is determined.

See [Template Tags/the_content « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content) and [Template Tags/the excerpt « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt)